# Listview updates only after changing screens in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout

So, here is my problem.

**Logic**:

Get the data from firebase.
Users can update the data, refresh the listview accordingly.

**Problem**:
Listview DOES update but, only after I change the screen to some other screen and return to the screen with the listview.

**Explanantion**:

The _postData array is made within the _PostsState.

The data is updated in the array when a user navigates to a new page and comes back with Navigator.pop()

The data is successfully updated and the array size does change but the change in UI is not reflected until screen is changed.

**Code**:

```
class Posts extends StatefulWidget {
  const Posts({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PostsState createState() => _PostsState();
}

class _PostsState extends State<Posts> {
  final DataRepository repository = DataRepository();
  final List<Post> _postData = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      getPosts();
      print('GET POSTS CALLED');
    });
  }
```

***SOME MORE CODE***

```
 SizedBox(
                height: 45.0,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Color(0xFF00AC97)),
                        shape:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0),
                        ))),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                            builder: (context) => AddPost()),
                      ).then((_) => {setState(() {})}); <- This doesnot work instantly
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      'Have anything to share? ',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'PoppinsLight',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        letterSpacing: 0.3,
                      ),
                    )),
              ),
```

SOME MORE CODE

```
      ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        key: UniqueKey(),
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: _postData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            key: UniqueKey(),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
             
                  Text(_postData[index].postContent.toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'WorkSansLight',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                        height: 1.75,
                      ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      )
```

***GETTING NEW DATA***

```
  Future getPosts() async {
    final QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> data = await FirebaseFirestore
        .instance
        .collection('posts')
        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
        .get();

    data.docs.forEach((QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc) {
      final Post postdata = Post.fromSnapshot(doc);
      setState(() {
        _postData.add(postdata);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: use the Stream Builder it will update continuously

Comment: You load data from the `Future` then need to use `FutureBuilder` and everything will work.

Answer (score 1):

You should use FutureBuilder Like This:

```
    FutureBuilder(
    future: getPosts(),
builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
if(!snapshot.hasData)
return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
else{
  ListView.builder(itemBuilder: itemBuilder)
}
  )
```

Comment: It did not work. FutureBuilder started to freeze my app.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the error. Data future is only called within init state. So the UI is not updating.